# How to add layers to a merged keras model?

Tags: python, keras, model

I want to add two layers a relu and a softmax ones to a merged model (on the output), here my merged model:

```
concat = concatenate([model1.output, model2.output], name='Concatenate')
final_model_output = Dense(20, activation='softmax')(concat)
final_model = Model(inputs=[model1.input, model2.input], outputs=final_model_output,
                name='Final_output')

final_model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is already in the code you attached.

You can add more layers as is done in the second line.

```
# model_name = Layer_name(...)(model_name)
final_model_output = Dense(20, activation='softmax')(concat)
```

Example:

```
concat = concatenate([model1.output, model2.output], name='Concatenate')
x = Dense(20, activation='softmax')(concat)
x = Dense(20, activation='relu')(x)
final_model_output = Dense(20, activation='softmax')(x)
final_model = Model(inputs=[model1.input, model2.input], outputs=final_model_output,
                name='Final_output')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the two layers are added perfectly

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I remember that I had a similar problem, I was using the "model.add (layer ...)" syntax all the time and when I saw this syntax somewhere I didn't know what was going on there: D